# Best design pattern for large tasks in Protractor JS

Tags: javascript, automation, jestjs, protractor

I am working on a test suite for a very mature website. There are lots of menus and deeply nested pages. I'm looking for some ideas on the best way to use Protractor JS testing framework to do repetitive series of tasks that I will need in many of my tests.

Currently I have my `.test.ts` files (contains the test and testing logic) and my `.po.ts` files (contains the page objects). Example of both below.

```
// header.test.ts

...
    const dh: DealerHeader = new DealerHeader();
    const loc: Locators = new Locators();
       it('Dealer Header Display', async() => {
        const dealerHeaderPrimaryDealerName = await dh.dealerHeaderPrimaryDealerName();
        
        await dealerHeaderPrimaryDealerName.isPresent().then(async function(present) {
            if(present) {
                await waitToBeDisplayed(dealerHeaderPrimaryDealerName);
                await expect(dealerHeaderPrimaryDealerName).toBeDisplayed();
                const dealerHeaderDealerRating = await dh.dealerHeaderDealerRating();
                await waitToBeDisplayed(dealerHeaderDealerRating);
                await expect(dealerHeaderDealerRating).toBeDisplayed();
        
                await click(dealerHeaderPrimaryDealerName);
                const dealerHeaderModel = await dh.dealerHeaderModal;
                await waitToBeDisplayed(dealerHeaderModel);
                await expect(dealerHeaderModel).toBeDisplayed();
            } else {
                await loc.changeDealer();
            };
        });
    });
...
```

```
// dealerHeader.po.ts
...
    async dealerHeaderPrimaryDealerName() {
        const dealerHeaderTopNavigationElement = await this.dealerHeaderTopNavigationElement();
        return dealerHeaderTopNavigationElement.element(by.xpath(
            './pce-dealerheader/div/section/section/div/span[contains(@class, "dealer-name")]'
        ));
    }

    get dealerHeaderModal() {
        return element(by.xpath(
            '//div[@class="dealer-modal"]'
        ));
    }
...

async changeDealer() {
 // is dealer set?
 // if dealer is set
    // click header to expand
    // click 'select dealer' button
    // goes to new locator page
    // scroll down
    // type zipcode in, press enter
    // get list of dealers, select random dealer
    // click dealer 'details' button
    // click 'change dealer' button

 // if no dealer is set
    // click header to expand
    // click 'select dealer' button
    // goes to new locator page
    // scroll down
    // type zipcode in, press enter
    // get list of dealers, select random dealer
    // click dealer 'details' button
    // click 'set dealer' button
}
```

My question is about the `changeDealer()` function. To "change a dealer" requires multiple clicks and a long series of steps to change. What is the best design pattern to create a function like this?

Comment: [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or [State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) pattern. Although the series of steps seem like they would work fine if they are straight up translated to code.

Answer (score 1):

how to implement it best? we really need to be experts in your application in order to answer accurately. Currently, you would be the best person to define the best approach

But what I found out for myself recently, is to follow development model  of the application itself normally is the best approach. That requires getting away from 'page objects' towards 'component objects'.

For example, your developers write dropdown component and reuse it in multiple places - go ahead and do the same. Write a dropdown component object that will have main locators and methods for manipulation of this html component (eg select option, get option count etc).

The developer creates an address form component, that requires smaller components like a dropwdown under the hood - do the same. Define another component object (or call it component controller) and define its locators and methods which WILL RELY ON ALREADY EXISTING CONTROLLER^^^

Then developers use this form component and create multiple instances - personal address, billing, mailing? do the same. At this point you just need to create an instance of the component defined in one place and reuse it three times

Why I think its the best? because you're reusing the code as much as possible and in the result avoid duplicate. and second, wether there should be changes in the application, likely they will happen on the component level and all you'll need to to is to correct its respective component's code